# Geolocation denied for HTML embedded site - anchor tag feature policy

Tags: iframe, anchor, content-security-policy, w3c-geolocation, http-permissions-policy

The iframe with allow="geolocation" works great.
But what if I want to load a link which calls getCurrentPosition() from a html anchor tag?

Example :
In iframe, I'll use

> `<iframe src="https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com" allow='geolocation'></iframe>`

I have a use case where a html embed link like

> `<a href="https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com">Click here to get geolocation</a>`

is embedded in a parent site.
The parent site loads the child link inside it's own iframe

It is to be noted that The parent site's iframe has the allow="geolocation" attribute .

In this case the request is silently denied with error

> errorCode :1

> errorMessage: "Geolocation has been disabled in this document by
> permissions policy."

The [feature policy](https://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) document point to iframe but what about anchor tag embeds?

I understand that I can use a iframe instead of anchor tag embed but the parent site only allows anchor tag's.

PS - This is my first question here. Please assist.

Note :

1. I also tried a random shot by including allow="geolocation" for anchor tag, but it doesn't work.
2. This seems to work on Safari (which I'm assuming is because Safari hasn't yet implemented feature policy for cross origin site requests)

**Edit 1 :**

I tried my use case in jsfiddle and notice that all scripts i give (iframe or anchor tag) are loaded inside jsfiddle's iframe

`<iframe name="result" allow="midi; geolocation; microphone; camera; display-capture; encrypted-media;" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads" allowfullscreen="" allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0" src=""> </iframe>`

If i load my iframe inside this, it works perfectly !(perfectly balanced, as all things should be...)

But if I load my anchor tag inside this, i get the error. As per [granty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823435/6779404)

the jsfiddle's iframe  with allow='geolocation' should set jsfiddle site's feature policy that all scripts loaded inside that iframe can access geolocation right ? Why does my iframe inside jsfiddle's iframe work but anchor tag doesnt ?

Note - I have no control over the top level site. I only code the scripts for `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com`

**SOLUTION (if you have control over top document's feature policy or   control over any intermediate `<iframe>` which have geolocation permission)** (derived from granty's answer)

I tried the suggested solution by changing the jsfiddle's iframe attribute via inspect element to

`<iframe name="result" allow="midi; geolocation https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com ; microphone; camera; display-capture; encrypted-media;" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads" allowfullscreen="" allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

To highlight, I added my site next to geolocation in allowlist like

> allow="midi; **geolocation `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com`** ;

and then loaded my anchor tag.
When the getCurrentPosition() was triggered from script loaded from `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com`, I got the browser prompt to Allow/Deny location sharing. I allowed and got the coordinates!

Wow! If only it could be as simple as editing the top level document's feature/permissions policy via inspect element.

But alas,I have no control over the top level document's feature policy. At least I understood what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Briefly**, you have to publish

```
Feature-Policy: geolocation https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com;
```

HTTP response header, when the server sends page into browser.

**TL; DR** or *What's going on under the hood*
The `allow="geolocation"` attribute is used to set Feature Policy (now it's renamed to Permissions Policy) inside iframe.
You use the `geolocation` directive with an emplty list of origins, therefore a [default policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy/geolocation#syntax) `geolocation 'src'` is applied. This means that inside iframe is allowed Geolocation API for scripts loaded from the same location as iframe - `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com`.

Pls note that for `allow="geolocation"` default policy is `'src'`(the origin from iframe's `src=`). But if you use directive `Feature-Policy: geolocation;`, the default policy for empty list is `'self'`.

To set Feature Policy in the main page (top level document) is intended the `Feature-Policy` header. If it didn't set, the default policy `geolocation 'self'` is applied. This forbids using Geolocation API for scripts loaded from `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com` origin.

Therefore use

```
Feature-Policy: geolocation https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com;
```

or

```
Feature-Policy: geolocation 'self' https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com;
```

if your own page uses geolocation too.

**Ref EDIT 1**
Jsfiddle's `<iframe allow="geolocation;"` means `<iframe allow="geolocation 'src';"`. It means only scripts loaded from the same origin(Url) as jsfiddle iframe can access Geolocation API. Therefore it does not allow your anchor tag from the `https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com` origin.

BUT [passing permissions of parent page into nested iframe](https://csplite.com/fp/test199/#no_FP) perform a tricky way. If some browsing context has some permission, it can grant it to any **nested** contexts independantly of its origin (if it creates this context by self).

So jsfiddle's iframe has permission for `geolocation`. Inside jsfiddle's iframe is placed your nested iframe having `allow='geolocation 'src'`.
Jsfiddle's iframe delegate its permission for geolocation to your iframe, of course the allowed origin is changed when permission passing into another iframe.

Yes, scripts loaded from third-party Urls can create iframe too, but they can't grant geolocation permission, because they do not have it - since loaded from origins for which geolocation is not allowed.

> the jsfiddle's iframe with allow='geolocation' should set jsfiddle site's feature policy that all scripts **loaded inside** that iframe can access geolocation right?

Not "loaded inside that iframe", but loaded from the same Url, as that iframe.
Otherwise, what's the point of specifying a list of allowed origins like `allow="camera 'self' https://www.youtube.com"`, if any not listed script can have access to your camera.

It's a bad practice to use hidden default, therefore you was mislead. Instead of:

```
<iframe allow="midi; geolocation; microphone; camera; display-capture; encrypted-media;"
```

should be:

```
<iframe allow="midi 'src'; geolocation 'src'; microphone 'src'; camera 'src';
  display-capture 'src'; encrypted-media 'src';"
```

Comment: Grateful for your answer @granty . Also it seems the link _default policy_ in your answer is not accessible.
I noticed a curious case in jsfiddle . Please refer the edit 1 in question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer to cover your EDIT 1 and replaced broken link.

Comment: Ok, i tried the solution you suggested and it seems this works only if I have control over the top document's feature policy right ?
(I edited the jsfiddle's iframe via inspect element to allow my site and it worked , but due to security policies i cant force this without the inspect element edit right ?)

Comment: You do not need control over the top document's feature policy. You just need to have control over any intermediate `<iframe>` which have geolocation permission. Insert into jsfiddle `<iframe allow="geolocation https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com;">` and inside such iframe your anchor tag will work. Never use `allow="geolocation"`, you do not see to whom you allow it. Always use `allow="geolocation https://siteWhichCallsGetGeolocation.com https://example.com https://trusted-domain.com;"` with explicit list of sources.

Comment: All "security policies" related to Feature policy is: *If any context has some permissions, it can delegate those to any nested context. If context didn't been granted some permission, it fails to delegate it via `allow=""` or Feature-Policy HTTP header to himself or nested context (iframe)*. BUT keep in mind that any "permission" always means "feature + list of allowed origins" related to scripts but not to "iframe itself". If script was loaded into iframe from not listed origin, such script will not get permission to access "feature".